# get the rules/ no of rules from an ApplicationListener grabbed using fromLookup ARN

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an already existing Load Balancer which has a listener.
I'm trying to add a rule to that `ApplicationListener` which i grab from `fromLookup` by giving the `listenerArn`

My issue is to know if there is a way to get the rules ( I just want a count so if it is an array that's also fine ) of the application listener I grabbed from arn. When I look from the AWS console there are 10 rules for that listener including the default (last) rule. My goal is to set the `priority` as number of rules instead of hardcoding.
`priorty` is also a compulsory field which takes a number according to [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationListenerRule.html) so I cannot ignore it hoping it will give least priority.

I went through [this github issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/4246) but that didn't seem to help

```js
const listenerArn = 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-central-1.....';
const appListener = ApplicationListener.fromLookup(this, `ALBListener-${props.stage}`, { listenerArn });

const applicationListenerRule = new ApplicationListenerRule(this, `MyAppRule-${props.stage}`, {
      listener: appListener,
      priority: 123 //i want to set it to least priority but possibly without hardcoding 
})
```

Would be glad to know if there are any workarounds
I'm using CDK v2.33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended. Its better to pass already existing rules count aside `listenerArn`. `priority` does't have to be hardcoded but it must to be static:

```js
const listenerProps = {
  arn: 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-central-1.....',
  latestPriority: 10,
};
const appListener = ApplicationListener.fromLookup(this, `ALBListener-${props.stage}`, { listenerArn: listenerProps.arn });

const applicationListenerRule = new ApplicationListenerRule(this, `MyAppRule-${props.stage}`, {
      listener: appListener,
      priority: listenerProps.latestPriority + 1
})
```

Comment: but here i have to hardcode as 10? the latestpriority value

Comment: yes its considered as a pre-existing value just as `arn`. Its common for `lookup` to ask props other than arn: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.SubnetAttributes.html

Comment: my plan is to save the arn in cdk.json file for each stage dev,demo,prod so do i need to save this as well

Comment: @cmgchess yes its great idea just use `this.node.tryGetContext('listenerLatestPriority')` later on! Just dont try generate priorities from array size etc.

Comment: i didnt go with this approach but went on with ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateInstance which creates a new listener with 1 (default) rule. I don't know if creating a listener is extra cost. I guess i'll accept this if this is the only way